# Which preposition can be used in the sentence “The bird is flying in/above the sky.”?

Tags: prepositions

I got confused what preposition exactly goes into the blank and why

> The bird is flying......the sky.(in/above)

Comment: ""Look! Up in the sky! It's a bird! It's a plane! It's Superman!"

Comment: Technically, a bird flies in **air**. But the common expression is *"fly **in** the sky"* - as you can find out using Google.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research/ELL"). Hi Rajesh, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1):

[The Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sky) defines "sky" as

> the upper atmosphere or expanse of space that constitutes an apparent great vault or arch over the earth

If you accept this definition then all the visible planets, stars, nebulae and other galaxies are part of the sky so the sky extends for billions of kilometres above the surface of the earth and there is nothing visible "above the sky". The bird, the International Space Station and the geostationary communication satellites are flying **in** the sky (although only in the closest part of it).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> in

In:

> the bird is flying within the boundaries of the sky

Above:

> the bird is flying outside the boundaries of the sky!? That would seem strange...

Comment: Hi Omega. If you're going to offer an answer, it's important to provide evidence to support it, so that we know you're providing an authoritative solution to the question, rather than a mere personal opinion. Perhaps a published dictionary definition or grammar guide? You can [edit] your answer to add this detail. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)